# Association referenda in Luhansk and Donetsk: What % of the population of the balloted areas are first-language Russian speakers?

Tags: russian-federation, ukraine, languages

Of the population of the areas of Ukraine, now occupied by Russia, where ballots are being conducted, what percentage speak Russian - as opposed to Ukrainian - as their first language?

Comment: Before or after the full-scale invasion and various population movements stemming from that? And who'd have reliable stats after?

Comment: [Prof. Mearsheimer](https://youtu.be/JrMiSQAGOS4?t=360) gives the Ukrainian-Russian split in maps [around 6 minutes]. Note this video is from 7 years ago

Comment: @Fizz I think it is relevant to use data that pre-dates the invasion. For it is the ratio who were living there prior to that event which would seem to me the best guide to determining its future.  I'm well aware that language is not everything - Ireland is still Ireland even though they nearly all speak English - but there was undoubtedly a large segment of the Ukrainian population which considered itself Russian.

Answer (score 4):

[According](https://www.rferl.org/a/russia-ukraine-elections-sham/32047316.html) to Radio Free Europe/Radio Liberty, Russia plans to hold votes in these regions (only using as a source because that's the best map I found)

[image]

As for language, it doesn't look like there was much of detailed survey since the 2001 census. According to that:

[image]

Someone with GIS skill might want to create a overlay of just the areas where Russia is holding these referendums.

Or if you want to ignore the finer front line and just want it aggregated by region, the same 2001 data:

[image]

Those latter two maps are from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_language_in_Ukraine#Current_usage_statistics).

---

Almar's comment does seem to have a point that the census “native language” question was apparently used by some (possibly many) Ukrainians to project an identity that may not have coincided with even with (then currently) language spoken "at home", as this [2002 paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.2747/1060-586X.18.3.213) by a Westerner relates:

> The [2001] Ukrainian census thus kept “native language” as its main language indicator. As argued previously, *rodnoy yazyk* does have the connotation of origins. (*Ridna mova* has exactly the same connotation in Ukrainian). This point was driven home to me a number of times as I was observing the census campaign in Kyiv in December 2001. Particularly illuminating was a conversation I had with a college student named Pasha
> (Kazymirov, 2001). The student, like most Kyivans, was perfectly fluent in Ukrainian, but preferred to use Russian at home and with his friends.
> Moreover, his parents raised him in Russian. No matter how “mother tongue” is defined—as “the first language(s) spoken in early childhood” (UN/Eurostat Recommendation), or “the language which the person commands best” (in the German tradition)—Pasha clearly has Russian as a
> mother tongue. Yet the census inquires about native language, not mother tongue, and he interpreted this to mean the language of his nationality. “Why didn’t you say that Russian was your *ridna mova*?” I inquired.
> “Because I am not Russian!” The same heartfelt affirmation of identity could be heard from taxi drivers, hotel administrators, and other random
> Kyivans I chatted with who, otherwise, merrily functioned in Russian. Suddenly, what Soviet and Western scholars had theorized about—that
> Soviet respondents tended to interpret the census question on *rodnoy yazyk* as a restatement of their nationality—was coming alive in the streets of
> Kyiv. [...]
>
> [T]he question on first
> language—native language—stands out as a case study in census identity
> politics. Analysts had noted how linguistically assimilated non-Russians
> during Soviet censuses tended to identify with the language of their
> nationality. The trend was unmistakable in Ukraine.
> The census behavior of “Russophone” Ukrainians—i.e., of people claiming a Ukrainian nationality
> but preferring to speak Russian at home—is intriguing. It is as if Russophone Ukrainians, who can speak Ukrainian but would rather not speak
> it if they don’t have to, are asserting that the Ukrainian language is,
> nonetheless, at the root of their identity. Russian-language activists in
> Ukraine tend to be dismissive of census results on *rodnoy yazyk* by focusing
> on the language actually spoken by half of the population (Russian). Yet
> census results on language, while selective (a question on conversational
> language was carefully avoided), are a fair representation of popular
> preferences. Russophone Ukrainians are not pressured to identify with the
> Ukrainian language (Ukrainian nationalists, as we saw, actually believe
> that the pressure favors Russian). These Ukrainians appear to be saying,
> through the census, that the Ukrainian language collectively defines their
> distinctiveness, even if they would rather use Russian in their daily lives.

Comment: One comment is that Ukraine has managed to spin "native language" as "the language of nation that you belong to", in that, ethnic Ukrainians are likely to answer Ukrainian in the polls even as their mother talked to them in Russian when they were born. Other sorts of maps give much larger prevalence than displayed here.

Comment: @alamar Various things contribute to a sense of nationhood as European history of the last two centuries has shown. Very few Irish speak Gaelic but in Ireland's case, as in Serbia/Croatia's case separate identities evolve from confessional differences - in Ireland Catholic/Protestant, in the Serbia/Croatia case they speak the same language, albeit using different scripts, but the all important thing is the Orthodox/Catholic split.  The confessional differences do not seem to play a part in Ukraine, so identity will cling to something else - most likely language.

Comment: @WS2: meh: Switzerland, Austria... all speak German by the Radio Moscow standards.

Comment: If Switzerland were to try making French the only state language, you would see Volksrepublik of Zürich really quickly @Fizz

Comment: @Fizz I've been in parts of Italy (e.g. Trentino) where all the road signs are in Italian, but people sit in the cafés speaking German and reading *Bild*. The great thing about the EU  is that it makes language and religion peripheral to people's sense of who they are - something that Ireland has now sadly lost.

Comment: @alamar: as we saw the Volksrepublik of Alsace?

Comment: @alamar Switzerland is an odd case.  The Swiss seem to identify with their cantons as much as with their nation.

Comment: @Fizz You could see the obvious problems with Alsace and Europe even had ECRML to prevent new Alsace question. First thing Ukraine does in 2014 after the coup is wiping their behind with ECRML.

Comment: @WS2 there are several linguistic parameters that vary across the Serbo-Croatian language space.  They are not necessarily aligned with confessional differences.  And Latin script is fairly common in Serbia.

Comment: @phoog I'm certainly no expert on the area, but isn't the important fact that Croatia was part of the Austro-Hungarian Empire?  And in that capacity the principal religion was Roman Catholic. Serbia, on the other hand saw itself as the nation that had expelled the Ottomans from Europe - with the support of pan-Slavist Russia, the eternal enemy of the Turks.

Comment: In other words Croats and Serbs are linguistically related but historically and culturally separated.

Comment: @WS2 Croats and Serbs have had distinct identities since long before the Austro-Hungarian empire -- the names appear in the historical record in the ninth century.  Similarly, the confessional differences go back to the 11yh century.

Comment: @phoog How interesting. Did the "distinct identities" exist prior to the 1054 East-West schism in the church? That must have played a big part in confirming them as different.

Comment: @WS2 If you ask a lot of Tirols population if they are italian you'd quickly find out that language is indeed a quite good representation of the perceived nationality.

Answer (score 3):

Almost all of them used either Russian language or Surzhik (a collection of wild varieties of Russian-Ukrainian mix or Ukrainian dialects without stable written form) when they were born. These areas do not have reservoirs of native Ukrainian speakers, as explained by the following map:

[image: Ukraine: languages spoken at home]

There are patches of Greek and perhaps even Serbo-Croatian there, but no Ukrainian.

The situation changes, though, and according to the following map, while most people still prefer to use Russian language, the difference is no longer that large, especially for Kherson region. It would be fair to say that significant number of people living in those regions are proficient in standard Ukrainian now, and some of them may prefer to use it in communication.

[image: Language preference in Ukraine]

This is a map of language preference in popular VK social network. You can see that most of south of Ukraine is still in blue (they prefer Russian), however it's lighter shades of blue meaning the actual difference may be 1.2x, e.g. 60% to 40%, from the looks of it.

You can also just do an internet search of [language distribution in Ukraine](https://yandex.ru/images/search?from=tabbar&text=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0) to get an endless supply of all kinds of maps and decide for yourself.

Comment: The first map is fairly useless as it doesn't indicate percentages.  (Furthermore, it doesn't mention Serbo-Croatian at all; where are you getting that from?)

Comment: Compared to other maps, the "useless" one is an actual product of a research institution. I'm referring to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slovianoserbsk

Comment: *"This is a map of language preference in popular VK social network"* - Not a very reliable proxy for actual language dominance if you ask me. VK is the Russian alternative to Facebook, because Facebook is banned in Russia. So people in Ukraine who are on VK instead of Facebook will predominantly be people with ties to Russia.

Comment: I was talking about the 2nd map you posted (in re LPR). On the 1st one I'm reserving judgement until I can find the publication.

Comment: People who read Ukrainian/Russian may be able to tell more on the "Subtelny line" https://journals.openedition.org/belgeo/38812

Comment: @alamar even if that map is perfectly accurate (and I have no reason to believe that or isn't), it is extremely imprecise.  For example, it shows the entire Luhansk oblast in red, yet according to the 2001 census, just under 68.8% of the population identified as Russian speakers and 30% as Ukrainian speakers.  The Ukrainian speakers didn't all leave over the intervening eight years.  The map is indeed useless for determining the percent of the population of any given place speaking any given language because it only identities a single dominant language for each part of the country.

Comment: @Philipp For many years, VK was *the* social network in Ukraine - it's not some fringe thing. People may also choose Ukrainian language interface as their political preference even if they really have to use Russian more on day-to-day basis, so biases may go either way.

Comment: Source: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhansk_Oblast.  The conclusion "These areas do not have reservoirs of native Ukrainian speakers" is not supported by the map, and it is furthermore incorrect.  Whatever the map's purpose may have been, it is not suitable for identifying the presence or absence of people speaking languages other than the locally dominant language, because it has no information whatsoever about such people.

Comment: As to Slovianoserbsk, 270 years after its founding, there is no longer much Serbian spoken there: "According to the 2001 census in Ukraine, the town had 61.72% Russian speakers and 37.54% Ukrainian speakers."

Comment: @phoog Ukrainian speakers are typically also Russian speakers (which is not always true the other way round). Russian being *lingua franca* in USSR, people often have to resort to it for information/communication, just like many people in the world need to know English to have access to books, internet communities, etc.

Comment: @RogerVadim of course, but the figures seem to be about primary language, since the figures sum to (just under)100%.  [This page](https://web.archive.org/web/20120222234720/http://2001.ukrcensus.gov.ua/eng/results/general/language/) suggests that the question was about "mother tongue."  But even (@ Fizz) if the census is invalid, it doesn't change the inutility of the first map. Concluding that there are no Ukrainian speakers in these areas is like looking at a map showing which US state went for which presidential candidate in 2020 and concluding that there are no Republicans in New York.

Comment: @phoog https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/53834/did-kyiv-national-linguistic-university-publish-a-map-showing-that-only-a-few-uk

Comment: @Philipp: The VK data is apparently from 2015, and some captions I found it with are bit different that selection of a primary language, but IDK muck about VK https://euromaidanpress.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/languagemap.png?fit=1172%2C545&ssl=1 the URL in the img links to https://texty.org.ua/articles/73060/Ukrajinska_mova_v_interneti_Torgivla_neruhomist_rozvagy-73060/ You are correct however that even back then, while VK beat FB in Ukraine, some used the latter too "The most popular in Ukraine: Vkontakte (13,218,915 visits per month), Facebook (8,729,179 visits per month)".

Comment: @Philipp: OTOH the results would probably have been the same with FB: "According to Facebook statistics, among the interface languages ​​in the Ukrainian segment of the social network, Russian dominates (75%), Ukrainian-language interfaces have 19% of users, 4.8% - English-language, 0.6% - Hungarian-language."

Comment: @Philipp: But the stats seem  to have changed since the full-scale invasion https://odessa-journal.com/research-what-language-do-ukrainians-use-in-social-networks-during-the-fourth-month-of-the-war/ Oh and VK is banned in Ukraine since 2017.

Comment: @Philipp: also "The key social networks Facebook, Twitter and Instagram showed the current Ukrainianization of users compared to the fall of 2020. If two years ago the share of posts in Ukrainian in these communities ranged from 13 to 27%, now it has reached two-thirds. In part, this is due to the entry into force of the law on customer service in Ukrainian in January 2021, as a result of which most organizations providing services switched to the state language of maintaining their pages." So it seems that a sizeable share were companies which tried to get Russian customers.

Comment: Crimea is missing from the second map.